# Jquery Libraries In Rails 3 App

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to rails and Jquery and am looking for some guidance on which libraries I should keep and which one I don't need. The other part of the question is I have read that I should use min.js files as they are quicker to load? Is this correct? what if I want to modify the library ( at some point in the future when I become more competent) or is there no need to modify a jquery library, as it does everything that is needed anyway.

Anyway currently I have the following in my javascript library

```
admin.js.coffee 
application.js  
bootstrap-alert.js  
calendar.js 
documents.js.coffee 
folders.js.coffee   
fullcalendar.js
gcal.js 
jquery-1.7.min.js   
jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js   
jquery-ui.js    
jquery-ui.min.js    
jquery.bookshelfslider.js   
jquery.bookshelfslider.min.js   
jquery.easing.1.3.js    
jquery.js   
jquery.rest.js  
jquery.ticker.js    
jquery_ujs.js   
rails.js    
site.js 
stickybar.jquery.min.js
stickysidebar.jquery.js 
turn.js
```

My application.js file looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Is there anything anyone can see that would cause me any issues? if I am calling a library within application.js, do I need the library in my Javascript directory?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should never modify the original Library File. Extend functionality.
2. Use Min in Production and Uncompressed in Development but having all the Libraries as min.js is not a problem if you dont think you are going to look into the Library Code.
3. rails.js is old, remove it. It was replace with jquery_ujs.js
4. I would call the js files directly rather than use require_tree .